# Firing <rich:select/> event after selection changes

Tags: jsf, events, richfaces, onchange, ajax4jsf

I'm using `<rich:select/>` element for selecting one element from list, and a need an action after user changes selected element. I wrote this:

```
<rich:select ... >
    <f:selectItems ... />
    <a4j:ajax listener="#{...}" event="change" render="..."/>
</rich:select>
```

and faced with a problem: `change` event occurs only when `<rich:select>`'s focus is lost. And `change` event do not work at all when user selects it's first value (from empty default value). 
**How can I invoke an action immediately when selection have changed?**

Comment: What version of richfaces is this?

Comment: Jorge Campos, `4.3.4`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `selectitem` event:

```
<a4j:ajax listener="#{...}" event="selectitem" render="..."/>
```

From the [Tag Library Doc](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/rich/select.html):

> onselectitem  - Javascript code executed when an
>   item is selected